# Why is my object not being pushed into a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I had the objects being pushed from the storeItems array, into the cartItems array and printing in the div successfully, but after adding more functionality it no longer adds to the array (checked via the console and there is a length value of 0). What am I not seeing??

I just need to transfer the user selected object from the storeItems array into the cart Items then it will print successfully

```
//Function to add an item to users cart & update total
function addItem() {
  var addId = document.getElementById("addItemId").value;
  var itemQty = document.getElementById("addItemQty").value;

  for (x = 0; x < storeItems.length; x++) {
    //Calling validation functions
    validateId();
    validateQty();


    if (addId === storeItems[x].id) {
      cartItems.push(new CartItem(storeItems[x].id, storeItems[x].name, storeItems[x].price, storeItems[x].qty, storeItems[x].shippingCost));
      displayCart();
    }

  }

  console.log(cartItems);
}
```

I just need to transfer the user selected object from the storeItems array into the cart Items then it will print successfully

Comment: At the very least I would properly declare my loop variables: `for (var x = 0; x < storeItems.length; x++) {`

Comment: Does your loop executes? Do you see any errors? Does your `addId` same as `storeItems[x].id` by types AND value

Comment: No errors, and thats whats ticking me off, im blindly trying things, @andy well observed correction there forsure but still no success

Comment: @Justinas do they have to match? should I declare the variable in the function as just simply "id" as thats what it is in the constructor

Comment: is it possible that `id` is a string in one place and a `number` in the other and you are using type comparisons with `===` and should instead use non-type comparisons using `==`, or casting the values to the same type?

Comment: There doesn't have to be an error. As Justinas asked, is that `if (addId === storeItems[x].id)` condition even being met for that object to be added to the array?

Comment: that was exactly it, I had the === operate, thank you! my goodness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you are using the correct comparison operator when comparing against a value and a text input. The text input will come back as a string no matter what the `type=""` value is set to.

So when comparing an input to actual data do one of the following:

- Use `==` instead of `===` to ignore/skip type comparisons
- Cast the input value to the type that it should be then you can use `===`

  - `parseInt(myInput) === myNonInput`
  - `new Date(myInput).getTime() === myNonInput.getTime()`
  - `myInput === myNonInput.toString()`
  - etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here i go,
I did some changes in your code, to make it workable for me.

have a look to my code

```
var storeItems = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

function addItem(addId, itemQty) {
function addItem(addId, itemQty) {
  for (x = 0; x < storeItems.length; x++) {
    //Calling validation functions
    if (addId === storeItems[x]) {
      cartItems.push(x);
    }
  }
  console.log(cartItems);
}

addItem(6);
```

According to my deduction, dear Watson, in your code following if condition is not working

```
 if (addId === storeItems[x].id) {
     ....
    }
```

debug this condition. this may help you !